# how can i fetch to fastapi

Tags: javascript, python, fetch-api, fastapi

After edit

```
const data = {
      text: text,
      translateTo: translateTo,
    };

    await fetch("http://localhost:8000/translate", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
```

```
backend
origins = [
    "*"
]


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)

@app.post("/translate")
async def translate(text: str = Body(), translateTo: str = Body()) -> str:
    return apiTranslateLang(text, translateTo)
```

I changed the name of the variable correctly and added up the Body next to the backend parameter then now the system show that this error

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/translate' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Though I accept all origin, I really don't know why this error caused.

Comment: Your request body has `translateTo`, but your backend is expecting `translate`. That is the problem. `async def translate(text: str, translate: str) -> str:` probably should be `async def translate(text: str, translateTo: str) -> str:`

Comment: `data` should be a JSON string? `body: JSON.stringify(data)`?

Comment: This is not working too :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to tell FastAPI that your `text` and `translate` fields are JSON body fields (and you need to use the correct name in your request - `translate` not `translateTo`):

```
async def translate(text: str = Body(), translate: str = Body()) -> str:
```

You can also create a Pydantic model that describes what you expect - this will automagically expected it as a JSON body:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class TranslationRequest(BaseModel):
    text: str
    translate: str


@app.post("/translate")
async def translate(translate_details: TranslationRequest) -> str:
    ...
```

Comment: can you check my code again? sorry for bothering

Comment: That error is usually caused by a server side error - check the log in your FastAPI application and see what it complains about. If you check your browser's developer tools and the Network tab you'll probably see that the response is an 500 error instead of the expected response.